# PHP array elements followed by ellipsis (. . .)

Tags: php

I am var dumping an array and see this:

```
 array (size=4)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            ...
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            ...
        2 => 
          array (size=2)
            ...
        3 => 
          array (size=2)
            ...
```

Are the array items there, just not listed, or is there a problem?

Comment: what does a print_r($array) look like?

Comment: That's a 'feature' of Xdebug. You can adjust the number of elements displayed with settings in PHP.INI. See the [reference](http://xdebug.org/docs/display)

Comment: That is the number of elements in the array.  It does not matter if the element is NULL or has data.

Comment: @dbinns66 print_r shows them, this clears things up thx all

Answer (score 0):

Replacing elements with ellipsis in `var_dump()` is a 'feature' of Xdebug. You can adjust the number of elements displayed with settings in PHP.INI.

Specifically `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` influences the how many nested levels of array elements and object properties are displayed.

There are a number of other settings that may also have some effect. See the [reference](http://xdebug.org/docs/display)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned this is because of XDebug.

It's available in the documenation located here, http://xdebug.org/docs/basic.

Here is a copy of it.

The setting that you are going to be interested is `xdebug.max_nesting_level` as right now it seems that you have it set to like 2 or 3.

So you can edit your php.ini and add the following

`xdebug.max_nesting_level = 10` which will state that it will go 10 levels deep before stopping.

Alternatively if you don't even want XDebug (as it'll improve performance), can you just disabled it all together by adding

`xdebug.default_enable = 0` in your php.ini file.

> xdebug.default_enable

**Type:** *boolean*, **Default value**: *1*

If this setting is 1, then stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event. You can disable showing stacktraces from your code with xdebug_disable(). As this is one of the basic functions of Xdebug, it is advisable to leave this setting set to 1.

> xdebug.force_display_errors

**Type:** *int*, **Default value:** *0*, **Introduced** in *Xdebug 2.3*

If this setting is set to 1 then errors will always be displayed, no matter what the setting of PHP's display_errors is.

> xdebug.force_error_reporting
>   Type: int, Default value: 0, **Introduced** in *Xdebug 2.3*

This setting is a bitmask, like error_reporting. This bitmask will be logically ORed with the bitmask represented by error_reporting to dermine which errors should be displayed. This setting can only be made in php.ini and allows you to force certain errors from being shown no matter what an application does with ini_set().

> xdebug.halt_level

**Type:** *int*, **Default value:** *0*, **Introduced** in *Xdebug 2.3*

This setting allows you to configure a mask that determines whether, and which, notices and/or warnings get converted to errors. You can configure notices and warnings that are generated by PHP, and notices and warnings that you generate yourself (by means of trigger_error()). For example, to convert the warning of strlen() (without arguments) to an error, you would do:

```
ini_set('xdebug.halt_level', E_WARNING);
strlen();
echo "Hi!\n";
Which will then result in the showing of the error message, and the abortion of the script. echo "Hi!\n"; will not be executed.

The setting is a bit mask, so to convert all notices and warnings into errors for all applications, you can set this in php.ini:

xdebug.halt_level=E_WARNING|E_NOTICE|E_USER_WARNING|E_USER_NOTICE
The bitmask only supports the four level that are mentioned above.
```

> xdebug.max_nesting_level

**Type:** *integer*, **Default value:** *100*

Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection. The value of this setting is the maximum level of nested functions that are allowed before the script will be aborted.

> xdebug.scream

**Type:** *boolean*, **Default value:** *0*, **Introduced** in *Xdebug >= 2.1*

If this setting is 1, then Xdebug will disable the @ (shut-up) operator so that notices, warnings and errors are no longer hidden.